# Objective C , Keyboard issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I am using XCode 4.2 .
is there a way to push the UITextField up when the user is entring text ?
the problem is that the UITextField is located behind the keyboard when it appears ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple [tutorial](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/32204-moving-uitextfield-when-keyboard-pops-up.html) on how to animate the textfield up when the keyboard comes up. The idea is to implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods like this

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
    // ANIMATE TEXTFIELD UP
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    // ANIMATE TEXTFIELD DOWN    
}
```

The tutorial has all the details along with working code.

Answer (score 1):

The one way is to simply manually shift the uitextfield up. You can simply use the delegate methods for uitextfielddelegate on begin editing and end editing to do your transformation.

Follow [this](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/32204-moving-uitextfield-when-keyboard-pops-up.html).

Comment: I am new to objective C developmment , how to manually do that ?

Comment: I sent you a link. Just click on the hyperlink on the word "this" in the post. Or you can simply google: "Shifting UITextField up". If you look harder you might even be able to find a solution using the search field for the site. Remember, been able to conduct proper research is a crucial ability every developer should have.